# Extract environment variable name from path in Java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have to extract the value of an environment variable using a java method.

My path is ${rootPath}/user/settings and the value I want to get is rootPath.

I tried the following but it says "not match found":

```
Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}").matcher("${rootPath}/user/settings").group(1);
```

If I use the replace method it replaces the ${rootPath} value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a `find()` call and verification.

Comment: You need to use the `replaceAll()` method in the right way :)

Comment: this is not the right approach use a suffix and substring, don't over use regexpr s.substring(0, s.length() - suffix.length())

Answer (score 1):

Using `replaceAll()` would not be a bad idea IMHO and the code would look quite simple :):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "${rootPath}/user/settings";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}.*","$1"));
}
```

O/P :

> rootPath